# Passing hook function to a component to be used in passed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can we pass hook as a function to a component and use it in that component?
Like in the example below I am passing `useProps` to `withPropConnector` which returns a `Connect` component. This `useProps` is being used in the `Connect` component. Am I violating any hook rules?

```js
// Landing.jsx

export const Landing = (props) => {
  const { isTypeOne, hasFetchedData } = props;

  if (!hasFetchedData) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  const renderView = () => {
    if (isSomeTypeOne) {
      return <TypeOneView />;
    }

    return <TypeTwoView />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        {renderView()}
        <SomeNavigation />
      </Wrapper>
      <SomeModals />
    </>
  );
};

const useProps = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  const { UID } = query;

  const { isTypeOne, isTypeTwo } = useSelectorWithShallowEqual(getType);
  const hasFetchedData = useSelectorWithShallowEqual(
    getHasFetchedData(UID)
  );

  const props = {
    isTypeOne,
    isTypeTwo,
    hasFetchedData
  };

  return props;
};

export default withPropConnector(useProps, Landing);



// withPropConnector.js

const withPropConnector = (useProps, Component) => {
  const Connect = (propsFromParent = emptyObject) => {
    const props = useProps(propsFromParent);
    return <Component {...propsFromParent} {...props} />;
  };

  return Connect;
};

export default withPropConnector;
```

Comment: I'm sure this works just fine. The only issue is that it is equivalent to using useProps in the Landing component. And since the only purpose of `withPropConnector(useProps, Landing)` is to bind an implementation of useProps to a component, which is what using a hook directly is, I don't see the purpose.

Comment: @windowsill Yeah, I could have used `useProps`  directly inside the `Landing` component. But I did this using `connector` so that I can unit test the `Landing` component directly through `props` arg, instead of mocking `useProps` when used directly inside `Landing` component

Comment: Then perhaps the parent of Landing could consume the hook and pass down the result as props. Then Landing would have the same api as it does here.

Comment: Yeah that is can done, But `useProps` is specifically for this `Landing` component.
And if we use it in the parent it might cause re-render in parent component when any store data changes like  `isTypeOne`, `isTypeTwo` or `hasFetchedData`.

Comment: If `useProps` is specific to `Landing` then it should just be used in `Landing`. If you  don't want to internalize it (*for testing or whatever*) then I suggest converting it to a HOC and just inject the values it returns as props. It is basically what you are already doing anyway with `withPropConnector`. Basically you've too many moving parts and needless complexity. Remember the KISS Principle (Keep It Stupid Simple).

Comment: Got it @DrewReese even i agree keeping it simple would be best, but i wanna try keep the UI part(`Landing` component) and data part(`useProps` hook) separate, rather than keeping everything together. Using some kind of HOC would be best.

Comment: Do you have the React-hooks [eslint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) installed? Surely it would help you here. Are you seeing React errors while the code is running? Surely it would inform if Hooks Rules were broken. If the answers are Yes, and No, then the answer to your question "Am I violating any hook rules?" is a pretty solid "No, you're not."